# How can I prevent water from beading on roof drain channel?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, roofing, sealant

I have a flat-roof above my flat, and have located the source of a leak which has been dripping for years.

I have bought some roof sealer (Roof Trade) and painted it over the channel where the leak originates from.

This has stopped the water coming through, but the water now travels down the channel in streams, and mini puddles (beads) are forming. I know these will eventually evaporate, but with the original surface, the water wouldn't 'bead' and would just spread out over the surface of the material.

Is there another product that I could apply to this to make it less smooth?? I was thinking of mixing sand into the sealant, but I'm just really guessing.

Or is it not a problem that the water is forming beads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beading isn't a problem. If it was, a persistent rain would also be a problem. Chances are the oils on the surface will eventually be removed by weather and the beading will subside anyway.

Comment: Great, thanks for the reassurance. I know this might be a separate question, but where the water has come through in the past, it has stained the wooden joist beneath. Is there a way of telling whether it has lost any structural integrity

Comment: You're right. It is.

Comment: @RichS unless you can push a screwdriver into the joist (indicating softening, regardless of the reason (water, termites, etc), the wood's probably OK>